# Can I programmatically create new passwords for Azure Service Principals?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to make a program that does secret rotation for Azure resources.  One of the secrets I want to rotate is a Service principal password.  I was wondering if I have the ability to programmatically do the following:

1. Make a new password for an existing service principal
2. Delete a password for an existing service principal

I haven't been able to find anything in the docs for the C# sdk, the REST API, the cli, or Powershell.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the powershell command below.

Create new password: [`New-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0)

Delete a password: [`Remove-AzureADApplicationPasswordCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0)

Comment: This works!  Is there a way to do it with a REST API?  I'm calling this via a c# program.

Comment: @RWood You could try to call the api `PATCH https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/applications/{application ObjectId}?api-version=1.6 `, for more details about the requset body, you could catch the request of the above powershell command via fiddler.

Answer (score 4):

That's relatively simple stuff that can be achieved with Azure CLI. Make sure you have Azure CLI 2.0 installed. To manage SP's use: `az ad sp` (check what it does with `az ad sp --help`). 
To manage credentials use: `az ad sp credential` (it has delete/list/reset commands available). Using this CLI commands you should be able to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Don't think it has an option for making a new password?  Only to delete, list, or reset.

Comment: That is what 'reset' command for (please follow the official Azure CLI guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp/credential?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-credential-reset)

Comment: Ah ok, I thought you could only overwrite a password with reset.  Adding the --append flag lets me do what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: No wonder I couldn't figure this out - why on earth would they use the same "reset" command to *add* a new credential?!

Answer (score 1):

Theres this little utility on Github, that rotates it through an azure function. C# code with Managed Identity

https://github.com/3mcloud/azure-keyvault-rotator

https://abschmidt.medium.com/rotating-service-principal-secrets-automatically-in-azure-key-vault-c4f04a84c9af

Answer (score 0):

Powershell and CLI:

`az ad sp credential reset --name <objectid>`